# Zend framework 2. Use module on homepage

Tags: zend-framework, module, frameworks

I start learning ZF2 and create my first products catalog module using [oficial tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html). It works fine in "site.name/catalog" section. My question is how can I use my catalog module on site homepage to show products?